# php extension fileinfo install in Ubuntu(15.10)

Tags: php, ubuntu

I have tried to install php fileinfo extension in Ubuntu(15.10) and getting errors:

```
sudo pecl install fileinfo
```

Error:

```
WARNING: "pear/Fileinfo" is deprecated in favor of "channel://php-src/ext/fileinfo/in php sources"
WARNING: channel "pear.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pear.php.net" to update
downloading Fileinfo-1.0.4.tgz ...
Starting to download Fileinfo-1.0.4.tgz (5,835 bytes)
.....done: 5,835 bytes
3 source files, building
running: phpize
Cannot find config.m4.
Make sure that you run '/usr/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module

If the command failed with 'phpize: not found' then you need to install php5-dev packageYou can do it by running 'apt-get install php5-dev' as a root userERROR: `phpize' failed
```

and then I tried this command:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev
```

Output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php5-dev is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.2.0-16 linux-headers-4.2.0-16-generic
  linux-image-4.2.0-16-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-16-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.2.0-16-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

How I can install php fileinfo extension?
How I can enable this extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This extension is enabled by default as of PHP 5.3.0.

Before this time, fileinfo was a PECL extension but is no longer maintained there.

Reference:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.installation.php

Comment: How I can enable this extension?

Comment: on Ubuntu it is enabled by default. Check your phpinfo if it is enabled. You can setup your extensions in php.ini

Comment: I checked in phpinfo and it is there:) 
how I can enable fileinfo in php.ini, I find `fileinfo` in php.ini and it seems it is not there!

Comment: Fileinfo has no configuration directives defined in php.ini

Comment: Try to use sample code and check if it works http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php  It should because fileinfo is enabled since PHP 5.3.0.